# Will permalinks work if blog is transferred to subdirectory?

Tags: permalinks, directory

How should I transfer my WordPress blog from the root of my domain to a sub-directory?

If everything including root in an installment of WP 3.2.1 were moved to a sub-directory, would the default permalink structure update to it? e.g. `domain.com/wp-sub` instead of `wp-domain.com`?

Also, should I modify any code or settings and, if so, what exactly?

Comment: They will work, you don't have to do anything

Answer (score 1):

Moving all files from root to a subdirectory will work. 
Don't forget the .htaccess file.
Just after move the files, you should change the root path in Configuration -> General - Site address. To the right direction.

i.e.
Moving from http://example.com to http://example.com/blog/

Answer (score 0):

I think you should also run a few MYSQL queries to make it work:

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://example.com', 'http://example.com/blog') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://example.com','http://example.com/blog');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://example.com/', 'http://example.com/blog');
```

If your permalinks are still not working, delete the .htaccess file, and go to Settings->Permalinks and click save to create the .htaccess file.